# Dynamic App Icon from Plist Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have searched online on how to change your app icon dynamically and all says you would need put the images under project directory. Is there any ways I can get an image from URL from my plist and show it as my app icon?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname), you *must* declare your alternate icons in your app's `Info.plist`, which is shipped in your app bundle. Since your app bundle is read-only, you can't add/edit entries in your `Info.plist`, which means it's impossible to download a new app icon from a server and set it as your app's icon